# Three.js OrbitControls - change autorotate direction

Tags: three.js

I am using the OrbitControls functionality in three.js. I have set autoRotate to true, and while it works, I want to be able to change the direction of the rotation around the y axis.

I have searched for the longest time and I can't find a setting for the auto rotate direction. Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `controls.autoRotateSpeed *= -1;`

Comment: Thanks so much @prisoner849 - that is exactly what I needed! Can't believe I missed that!